# "Artifacts" while streaming images in c#

Tags: c#, image, stream, artifacts

I wanted to create a project for streaming multiple images through net. I just wanted to start with small, functional code but already encountered a funky problem for me. Image is received, but it contains graphical bugs like its only a part of it.

Sadly cant show images cause of low rputation, here is link.
http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/1508/buggedy.jpg

Of course, million dollars for answer. ^^

```
TcpListener listener;
TcpClient client;
TcpClient datatoclient;
NetworkStream stream;
```

Host part:

```
listener = new TcpListener(5000);
listener.Start();
datatoclient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream nowystream = datatoclient.GetStream();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes("default.jpg");

switch (trackBar1.Value)
{
      case 0:
          image = File.ReadAllBytes("mirrion.jpg");
          break;
      case 1:
          image = File.ReadAllBytes("tenis.jpg");
          break;
      case 2:
          image = File.ReadAllBytes("marisasold.jpg");
          break;
}


// get the image size in bytes
int numberOfBytes = image.Length;

// put the size into an array
byte[] numberOfBytesArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(numberOfBytes);

// send the image size 
nowystream.Write(numberOfBytesArray, 0, numberOfBytesArray.Length);

// send the image 
nowystream.Write(image, 0, numberOfBytes);
```

Client part:

```
client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5000);
stream = client.GetStream();

byte[] data = new byte[4];
// read the size
stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
label1.Text = size.ToString();

// prepare buffer
data = new byte[size];

// load image
stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

// save image to file for test
File.WriteAllBytes("received.jpg", data);

MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(data);

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(MS);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stream.Read` doesn't guarantee that it will read `data.Length` bytes. Instead it returns number of bytes read. So you should check its return value and continue reading till you get all the bytes.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.90).aspx (Section `Return Value`)

Thr read method can be something like this

```
void Read(Stream stream, byte[] buffer,int offset,int len)
{
    int read = 0;
    while (read < len)
    {
        read += stream.Read(buffer, offset + read, len-read);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks a lot! My bad, I thought that stream.Read will wait till it reads all needed data.